# How to create a filter in SQLite database across multiple tables?

Tags: python, sqlite

I am looking for a way to create a number of filters across a few tables in my SQL database. The 2 tables I require the data from are `Order` and `OrderDetails`.
The `Order` table is like this:

```
------------------------------------
| OrderID | CustomerID | OrderDate | 
------------------------------------
```

The `OrderDetails` table is like this:

```
----------------------------------
| OrderID | ProductID | Quantity | 
----------------------------------
```

I want to make it so that it counts the number of instances a particular OrderID pops up in a single day. For example, it will choose an `OrderID` in `Order` and then match it to the `OrderID`s in `OrderDetails`, counting the number of times it pops up in `OrderDetails`.

```
-----------------------------------------------------------
| OrderID | CustomerID | OrderDate | ProductID | Quantity |
-----------------------------------------------------------
```

The code I used is below here:

```py
# Execute SQL Query (number of orders made on a particular day entered by a user)
cursor.execute("""
SELECT 'order.*', count('orderdetails.orderid') as 'NumberOfOrders'        
from 'order'
left join 'order'
on ('order.orderid' = 'orderdetais.orderid')
group by
    'order.orderid'
""")
print(cursor.fetchall())
```

Also, the current output that I get is this when I should get 3:

```
[('order.*', 830)]
```

Comment: Don't put identifiers in single quotes. Though this is possible in some contexts in SQLite (e.g. table names) in others it marks a string literal (as it does in standard SQL).

Comment: Also I don't get why you join `orderdetails` at all. The number of orders is the number of records in `order`, isn't it? To clarify what you want, you should [edit] the question and add the `CREATE` statements for the tables along with `INSERT` statements for sample data and the result you expect with that sample data in tabular text form.

Answer (score 0):

Your immediate problem is that you are abusing the use of single quotes. If you need to quote an identifiers (table name, column name and the-like), then you should use double quotes in SQLite (this actually is the SQL standard). And an expression such as `order.*` should not be quoted at all. You are also self-joining the orders table, while you probably want to bring the orderdetails.

You seem to want:

```
select
    o.orderID,
    o.customerID,
    o.orderDate,
    count(*) number_of_orders
from "order" o
left join orderdetails od on od.orderid = o.orderid
group by o.orderID, o.customerID, o.orderDate
```

`order` is a language keyword, so I did quote it - that table would be better named `orders`, to avoid the conflicting name. Other identifiers do not need to be quoted here.

Since all you want from `orderdetails` is the count, you could also use a subquery instead of aggregation:

```
select 
    o.*,
    (select count(*) from orderdetails od where od.orderid = o.oderid) number_of_orders
from "order" o
```

Comment: One more question, how should I edit it such that it rearranges the columns after the query in the print section so it displays it like 
| CustomerID | OrderID | OrderDate | Number of Orders |

Comment: @AlexRavenwood: the query gives you the columns in that order already.